# Start position of moving Sprite

Tags: python, pygame

I have four moving sprites, which are currently at the same position. They were meant to have seperate positions, but I failed at placing them using a variable as position.

```
position =(50,50)#position for sprite 2
while running:
rect = rect.move(speed)

    if rect.left < 0 or rect.right > 380:
        speed[0] = -speed[0] * e
        pygame.display.update()
    if rect.top < 0 or rect.bottom > 370:
        speed[1] = -speed[1] * e
        pygame.display.update()
    window.blit(sprite, rect )
    window.blit(sprite2, rect, position)
    window.blit(sprite3, rect)
    window.blit(sprite4, rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\eskappa1.py", line 94, in <module>
    window.blit(sprite2, rect, position)
TypeError: Invalid rectstyle argument
```

Comment: I could not find the solution by using those answers

Comment: Do you have an solution for this because I honestly can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing window.blit(sprite2, rect, position) you can just pass it the position only and it will draw the surface with the upper left hand of it at the position coordinate. for example:

```
position = (50,50)
window.blit(sprite2, position)
```

see the documentation for pygame surfaces if you want to know more: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit

Comment: But by doing this, it loses its ability to move

Comment: @user3602565 Why should it? Just change `position`.